# How can I generate iOS endpoint libraries from android studio

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

I created an Android client / appengine cloud endpoints server project with Android Studio. I would now like to generate the iOS Objective-C sources of the endpoint to use for an iOS port of the Android client. How can I generate the source? I cannot find the endpoints.sh or any other command line tools with the project. Also, the gradle sources for the endpoints plugin seems to have java-libs only hardcoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't generate an iOS client from Android. You need a computer with Xcode installed. See [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios#Java_Compiling_the_client_library_generator_and_generating_your_library). The endpoints SDK only allows Java client library generation, because of this, and also because most other clients are generated dynamically and/or external from the client generator service.